# macOS Catalina does not allow incoming connections from local network. Firewall is down

Tags: terminal, network, firewall

I starting facing this issue some days ago. Even when the firewall is down, I can't reach my mac from my local network. Ping is not responding neither. Some test I've done:

**From my console**

```bsh
nrossi@~$ netstat -an | grep 8080                                              
tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN 

nrossi@~$ sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getglobalstate
Firewall is disabled. (State = 0)

nrossi@~$ ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' 
10.1.2.123

nrossi@~$ curl -I 10.1.2.123:8080                                              
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 18 Mar 2021 13:06:46 GMT
```

**From other computers**

```
nrossi@~$ curl -I 10.1.2.123:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.1.2.123 port 8080: Operation timed out

nrossi@~$ ping 10.1.2.123
PING 10.1.2.123 (10.1.2.123): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

Any help ?

Comment: We need to understand more about your networking topology, because this may be a simple routing issue. How are your Mac and other systems physically attached to your network? WiFi, Ethernet? Are they connected using a hub, switch, router?

Comment: Hi Pion, they are connected to WiFi. I have several devices connected to the same WiFi (windows laptops, printers and mobile phones) and I can reach other IPs or ports. Let me give some examples: 1) windows → printer (http 80): ok, 2) mac → windows (http 80): ok, 3) mobile → printer: (http 80): ok, 4) windows → mac: timed out, 5) mobile → mac: timed out. Is there anything I can do to give you more information?

Comment: What router do you have? Does it have diagnostic tools that allow you to ping and/or port scan its clients? What subnet are your Mac and other clients on?

Comment: It's a Linksys EA7500. The ping from the diagnostic tool to the mac returns "5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss" but pinging to other devices works well. I don't think it's related to the router because it is also happening at work where nobody is having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the solution to this issue. First of all I listed the macos extensions:

```bsh
$ kextstat | grep -v com.apple

Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>
  115    0 0xffffff7f83ef2000 0x29000    0x29000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (7.5.1) D0CC7B8F-1F62-33B1-BE6B-B5573D2A607B <8 6 5 3 1>
  176    0 0xffffff7f846db000 0x31000    0x31000    com.checkpoint.cpfw (1.0) A38506C9-F70F-356C-9AF5-67B70391CF36 <6 5 3 1>
```

The checkpoint extensions was my first candidate to remove. So I run the uninstaller:

```bsh
$ cd /Library/Application\ Support/Checkpoint/Endpoint\ Security
$ sudo ./uninstall
```

Everything is working fine now.